# Will using multiple stylesheets affect the performance of an Angular application?

Tags: css, angular

Imagine you have 2000 lines of CSS to style an Angular application. Now, take the following scenarios:

- **A:** all the styles live in a single CSS file.
- **B:** the styles are split in two different files.

Would the latter harm performance in a substantial way?

Answer (score 1):

Splitting into multiple files and lazyloading them would be the best way to go about it as far as perfomance is concerned. Using a sing file is much better than using multiple files that are loaded at the same time(i.e without lazy loading)